# position absolute and bottom not working in IE9

Tags: html, css, styles, internet-explorer-9, footer

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative">
    <div id="footer" style="position: absolute; bottom: 25px; margin-top: 10px; left: 0px">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to align my footer below the container that is bottom of the page. I don't need a fixed footer. so I have used position absolute here.
This working fine in all browsers except IE9. I have tried with `position: relative` too. Nothing has changing in `IE9`.

https://jsfiddle.net/13grvhyt/

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle of your code?

Comment: I have added jsfiddle.

Comment: @Please add complete code so that i can see the problem in fiddle. Right now i don't see even `footer`

Comment: Can you please check now ? I have edited

Comment: I don't see any change, still the same (

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
}

.container h1{
color:white;
}

.footer{
position: absolute; 

  left: 0px
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
  text-align:center;
}
.footer h1{
 font-size:22px;
  color:white;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <h1>I am Container <h1>
    
    </div>
<div class="footer" > <h1> I am Footer</h1>
     </div>
```